# how to check DRAM and memory storage in linux

Tags: linux, memory, ram

I am new to linux. May I know how can I check **DRAM** and **memory storage** in linux?
Thank you.

Comment: Not a programming question. It's also not clear how you're differentiating between DRAM and memory storage here. You should ask on [unix.se], but clarify the question first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DRAM expands to Dynamic Random Access Memory. It makes use of memory cells consisting of capacitor and transistor to store each bit of data. The capacitor is either charged or discharged. 0 and 1 are respectively used to represent these. The charge on the capacitor leaks gradually and hence a periodic refresh is needed which rewrites the data back to the capacitors.

It is typically used in the main memory of the computer.

DRAM is categorized as volatile memory as it loses data when the power supply to it is removed. It too has the property of data remanence (very limited).
you can use code below to check the information of RAM:

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

also :

```
htop
```

for DRAM i think the command bellow could help you

```
sudo dmidecode
```

read [this article](https://www.linuxtechi.com/dmidecode-command-examples-linux/)

Comment: How about memory storage?